# Page_Load firing twice regardless of what i do

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a simple asp.net login page. Yesterday, the code was working fine. Today, it isn't.

The only thing that changed between yesterday and today is that I shut down my pc and started it again today.

The problem is that Page_Load is firing twice (I checked all the answers/solutions, and none worked (image with empty src, handling the page_load manually, setting autoEventWireUp to false...)) none of these seemed to do the trick.

PLEASE can someone help me figure out why this is happening?

#### Here is the code for the page and its code behind:

```
<%@ Page Title="Login" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="MatchingWebsite.Login" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1><%: Title %></h1>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </section>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2 align="center">Looking for someone to spend your time with? Want to have fun with someone you like?<br />You've come to the right place!!</h2><br /><br /><br />
    <img alt="Cupid" src="Images/images.jpg" align="left" />
    <img alt="Couple" align="right" src="Images/matchmaking.jpg" /><br /><br />
    Username:<br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="UserLogIn" runat="server" Width="174px"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
    Password:<br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="UserPass" runat="server" Width="175px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox><br />        
    <asp:Label ID="LoginError" runat="server" Text="Wrong Username/Password Combination. Try again." Visible="False"></asp:Label><br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" OnClick="Login_Click" Text="Login" Width="81px" />
    <asp:Button ID="NotRegistered" runat="server" Text="Not Registered?"             Width="150px" OnClick="Not_Registered" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1
        {
            width: 300px;
            height: 113px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
```

#### And here is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MatchingWebsite
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Service1 proxy = new Service1();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["username"]!=null && !IsPostBack)
                Response.Redirect("~/EnterMyInfo.aspx");
        }
        protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string user = UserLogIn.Text;
            string pass = UserPass.Text;
            if (user == "" || pass == "")
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=\"JavaScript\">alert(\"Username/Password cannot be blank.\")</SCRIPT>");
            else
            {
                if (proxy.login_service(user, pass))
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/EnterMyInfo.aspx");
                }
                else
                    LoginError.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        protected void Not_Registered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/SignUp.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's driving me cracy is the fact that the code was working yesterday, and today it just stopped working although nothing changed. (Except for shutting down my computer normally yesterday).

Comment: Did you try to restart the web application again...?

Comment: I tried restarting the web application, and the whole PC. None of it worked. Also, I tried debugging to see exactly what's happening... When i press login, first page_load is called due to a postback (which is understandable) but then it gets called a second time for no apparent reason (the second time isn't a postback)

Comment: But did you get any errors?

Comment: No errors... It compiles and runs fine... Other pages work fine... Just the login doesn't work.

Comment: just now test your code in visual studio..everything works fine for me, did you get any javascript errors in developer tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the webpage is really loaded twice. Check your javascripts (or any AJAX components?), or use the browser's debug console to monitor the network requests being sent. Try adding empty methods on the PreInit, PostInit (etc.) events and set breakpoints too, I bet those are hit twice as well.

Comment: But yesterday it wasn't!! How could this happen? Also, I do not have any ajax components and my aspx is free of javascript scripts.

Comment: After some more debugging, I found out that Page_Load is being called (and NOT as a postback) exactly after the Response.Redirect in the code behind. Any idea why?

Comment: Turns out the page was being loaded twice because of a glitch in my code (typo in setting the Session value)... thanks everyone and sorry if i cause any inconveniences.